# Google Consumer Survey not appearing on my site

Tags: javascript, survey, consumer

I want to survey website visitors on my site. I really like the delivery mechanism that I have seen demo'd in Google Consumer Surveys.

I cannot get the survey to render on my site. The status within the google consumer survey control panel indicates that it is 'enabled' but there are zero responses as it won't popup.

The script is

```
<script async="" defer="" src="//survey.g.doubleclick.net/async_survey?site=[mysiteid]" </script>
```

and is placed above the

See it view-source:http://www.wholesomeone.com/

I tried to add http: before the // but that had no apparent effect.

It seems so simple, but I am so frustrated and of course there is no way to reach google and ask them.

Help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it did get working but not by anything that I did. Google made some adjustments on their end that enabled it to function.

Answer (score 2):

Are you in the US, UK or CA? Right now Google Consumer Surveys website satisfaction surveys are only supported in those countries. The survey won't show if your IP address is located somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am in the US and my site is hosted on Rackspace in the US. 98.129.229.207 Location doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: One other data point for diagnosis. I created a plain html page without Wordpress or any potential code conflicts at http://wholesomeone.com/testsurveypop.html and still the survey won't render.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add http: before // and it needs to added as given by google consumer survey page.

After you have created the survey,did you clicked the "Activate Survey" button ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using the code exactly as provided by google with the just //. Yes, i clicked the Activate button, and received the confirming email. Current status says that the survey is active, but has 0 responses.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to make sure of:

1. Go to http://www.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/ and click Setup next to your survey.
2. In Survey Settings below, click to expand Advanced Settings and change "First Survey Timing", "Survey Frequency", "Show survey to every" "Wait X minutes until showing a survey again after disappearing" all to the value of "1".

Some of the fields will have placeholder value of 1 (dim-style text), but don't be fooled like I was, and explicitly set those values to "1". After you've successfully viewed your surveys you can play around with those values to meet your needs.

This should do it (also makes sure you read and follow other answers on this page).